# Shortcut to turn PHP xdebug ON

Tags: php, powershell, xdebug

A script to turn xdebug On works but I cannot figure out out to create a shortcut to run it. If I open administrator PowerShell in `C:\Users\George\Desktop\Development\Config Files`, the command `.\PHPxDebugOn` will restart Apache with the modified php.ini.  (There's also a PHPxDebugOff.ps1 to turn xdebug off.)  Clicking on the shortcut (with Run as administrator ON) just flashes a black screen but no change to Apache.

script:

```
$iniFile = "C:\Users\George\Desktop\Development\Config Files\php.ini"
$xFile = "C:\Users\George\Desktop\Development\Config Files\xdebug.ini"
$phpIniFile = "C:\PHP\php.ini"

get-content $iniFile, $xFile | set-content $phpIniFile

C:\Apache24\bin\httpd -k restart
```

shortcut target:

`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file "&C:\Users\George\Desktop\Development\Config Files\PHPxDebugOn.ps1"`

Comment: Is there a reason why xdebug isn't constantly enabled on your local machine? I'd say: use xdebug when developing, if you're done: push to server where xdebug isn't even installed. No need to restart apache whenever you want to debug some code

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I keep xdebug off unless I need it for debugging because it makes a significant difference in response time.  Most of the development is done with functional tests and I get impatient with xdebug. Apache is run only for development.

Comment: An alternative would be to create a parallel vhost with its own ini settings eg local.dev for non xdebug environment, and localx.dev pointing to the same files, but with xdebug enabled. Changing the url would then automatically enable/disable xdebug without having to restart the server

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem An interesting approach - I'll see what I can do with it.  But I'd still like to know what's missing about the PowerShell shortcut. I figure it's about time I learned how PS worked - MS is a bit short on docs on scripts & shortcuts.

Comment: Add `-NoExit` to your shortcut target and you can keep the window open. There's also chance you may need to add `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks for the suggestion - Apache now with fastcgi & two environments/php.ini.   Very cool!

Comment: @BoogaRoo Thanks for the suggestion, but no joy.  Still the quick flash of screen and no change.

Comment: @geoB: You're welcome. Though I've not answered the actual question (not familiar with PS, being more of a Bash person myself). Would it be OK for me to post my comment as an answer. The way I look at this question, it's more of an X-Y-Z problem (I'm trying to do X, using Y, whereas my answer is: try Z instead of Y to solve the problem)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'll be happy to accept your suggestion as a solution.  It is both a more elegant solution to the fundamental problem and a more readily achievable solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as my comment is, according to the OP, a better approach to the problem, I'll post it here as an answer:

What I'd do is create a second virtual host that points to the same source, but loads separate php.ini files to enable xdebug on that vhost. That way, you can simply use `http://local.project.dev` and `http://local.project.debug` to run the same code with xdebug enabled. This way, you don't have to restart apache each time you want to use xdebug to step through the code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the shortcut target.

Removing the `&` symbol should resolve the script not running, provided the path is correct.

PowerShell exits without attempting to run the script if the target file in the shortcut is invalid in any manner. Unless everything in the command can be evaluated/parsed/retrieved, the default behavior is to stop everything and report the error. That explains why the window disappeared, even with the `-NoExit` parameter specified. PowerShell does present the error in the brief moment that window is visible. Screen refresh rates and processor speeds being what they are, screenshots were a bit of a challenge to catch.

Sample 1:`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -file "&C:\scripts\hello.ps1"`

[image: Invalid shortcut file path]

Sample 2:`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -file "C:\scripts\hello.ps2"`

[image: Invalid extension]

Sample 3(successful):`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -file "C:\scripts\hello.ps1"`

[image: Successful PowerShell shortcut execution]

Notes:

- Repro environment: Windows 7 Enterprise with Powershell 5.0 April 2015 preview
- The .ps2 file extension may be valid on some systems
- You can skip loading PowerShell profiles by using the `-NoProfile` parameter
- [File must be the last parameter in the command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx), because all characters typed after the File parameter name are interpreted as the script file path followed by the script parameters

Comment: I've upvoted because your answer led me to a proper shortcut.  I learned that `-file -NoExit` is improper syntax: it reads `-NoExit` as the file name.  Plus, I had to comment out everything in `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` to make it work.  Now I have to figure out what I can put back in.  Since the fundamental problem was xdebug, not PowerShell, I've accepted the @EliasVanOotegem answer.  Thanks for setting me on the path.